# Program that displays each digit on an integer in english doesn't work with an integer beginning with "0"

Tags: c, loops, integer

I have an assignment were I have to write a program that takes an integer keyed in from the terminal and extracts and displays each digit of the integer in English. I'm not able to use arrays or recursion, we're just starting with programming.

For example:
"123" returns "one two three"

My program is working well (for the most part), but the problem is that when you enter something like "0123" in the terminal the program returns "eight three"... WTH??

This is my code:

```
// Program that takes an integer and displays each digit in English

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int num, digit;
    int reversed = 0, backupZero = 0;

    printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    if (num == 0) // In case the input is just "0"
    {
        printf("zero");
    }

    while (num > 0) // Loop to reverse the integer
    {
        digit = num % 10;
        reversed = (reversed * 10) + digit;

        if ((reversed == 0) && (digit == 0)) // If the integer finishes in zero
        {
            ++backupZero; // Use this to add extra zeroes later
        }

        num /= 10;
    }

    while (reversed > 0)
    {
        digit = reversed % 10;
        reversed /= 10;

        switch (digit)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("one ");
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("two ");
                break;

            case 3:
                printf("three ");
                break;

            case 4:
                printf("four ");
                break;

            case 5:
                printf("five ");
                break;

            case 6:
                printf("six ");
                break;

            case 7:
                printf("seven ");
                break;

            case 8:
                printf("eight ");
                break;

            case 9:
                printf("nine ");
                break;

            default:
                printf("zero ");
                break;
        }

    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter < backupZero; ++counter) // Prints the extra zeroes at the end
    {
        printf("zero ");
        --backupZero;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Probably is something on the mathematics, I admit I'm not good at it.

Comment: It's the property of "%i", which can handle other bases too. With "%d" 0123 is 123, as %d stands for decimal to integer conversion.

Comment: Oh I see! It was so simple, thank you very much for the comment! I'll remember this :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read in the number with

```
scanf("%i", &num);
```

You are letting `scanf` infer the base of the number. Numbers starting with `0` followed by other digits are interpreted as octal. So `0123` is not the same as `123`. It is in fact, `83`.

```
0100 = 64
 020 = 16
  03 =  3
---------
0123 = 83
```

To read the number as base 10, use

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Comment: 0123 is not octal per se; It's octal only in context of %i, or integer literals in C. atoi("0123"); wouldn't behave like that.

Comment: @juanchopanza We did have a lecture on this and I completely forgot, thank you very much, your answer was very useful! I need to remember about the differences of %i and %d.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle numbers that start with `'0'`, then I suggest that you read the user input as a string (array of characters) rather than as an integer.

In addition to that, instead of "doing a switch" on each character, you can use a simple array in order to map the correct word to each digit.

Here is one way for implementing it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LEN 100

const char* digits[] = {"zero","one","two"  ,"three","four",
                        "five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

int main()
{
    int i;
    char format[10];
    char str[MAX_INPUT_LEN+1];
    sprintf(format,"%c%us",'%',MAX_INPUT_LEN); // now format = "%100s"
    scanf(format,str); // will write into str at most 100 characters
    for (i=0; str[i]!=0; i++)
    {
        if ('0' <= str[i] && str[i] <= '9')
            printf("%s ",digits[str[i]-'0']);
        else
            printf("invalid character ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh I'm sure that this is a much more efficient way to do it but I wasn't allowed to use arrays or recursion, still thanks for your answer because I'm sure it'll come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wow. It took me 3 or 4 hours to write following code. I'm into [c](/questions/tagged/c) only first week, so please be considerate. 
Update: added working minus + some comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)

{
    int num, count, user, out;
    count = 0;

    printf("Type in any int: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    // adding minus to the beginning if int is negative
    if (num < 0) 
    {
        num = -num;
        printf("minus ");
    }
    user = num;

    // creating a power to the future number
    while (num != 0)
    {
       num = num / 10;
       count++;
    }

    int i2;
    i2 = count;

    // main calculations: dividing by (10 to the power of counter) and subtracting from the initial number
    for (int i = 0; i < i2; i++)
    {
        out = user / pow(10, count - 1);
        user = user - out * pow(10, count - 1);
        count--;

        switch (out)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("one ");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("two ");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("three ");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("four ");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("five ");
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("six ");
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("seven ");
                break;
            case 8:
                printf("eight ");
                break;
            case 9:
                printf("nine ");
                break;
            case 0:
                printf("zero ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
         }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes:

```
if ((reversed == 0) && (digit == 0)) (incorrect)
if ((reversed == 0) || (digit == 0)) (correct)
```

And in the last loop you should remove

```
--backupZero;
```

And code will read numbers better